# SQL condition based on number on field name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table containing numbers of people in each area, by age.
There is a column for each age, as shown in this table (junk data):

| Area | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 90+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | 65 | 45 | 20 | -- | 66 |
| B | 442 | 456 | 124 | 422 | -- | 999 |
| C | 442 | 99 | 88 | 747 | -- | 234 |

I need to group these figures into age bands (0-19. 20-39, 40-59...)
eg:

| Area | 0-19 | 20-39 | 40-59 | 60+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 789 | 689 | 544 | 1024 |
| B | 1564 | 884 | 1668 | 1589 |
| C | 800 | 456 | 456 | 951 |

What is the best way to do this?

I could do a simple SUM as below, but that feels like a massive amount of script for something that feels like it should be straightforward.

```
SELECT 
[0]+[1]+[2]+...[19] AS [0-19],
[20]+[21]+[22]+...[39] AS [20-39]
...
```

Is there a simpler way? I'm wondering if PIVOT can help but am struggling to visualise how to use it to get my desired result.
Hoping I'm missing something obvious!

---

**EDIT** This is how the data has been supplied to me, I know it's not a great table design but unfortunately that's out of my hands.

Comment: You really have a table with 92 columns?

Comment: @SalmanA - yes, unfortunately so. This is how it's been supplied (not my design).

Comment: If you can't change your design, then the query you posted above is as good as you can get.  Well you _could_ try to use dynamic SQL to programatically sum the columns, but that might result in even more code.

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach? Pivot/unpivot will still require that you type the name of those 90 columns. And the query will be more expensive.

Comment: @SalmanA - good point. Neither is ideal. The approach above will work, was just hoping a more succinct method exists.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a view on top of your table like so:

```sql
CREATE VIEW v_t_normal
SELECT Area, Age, Value
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (0,  [0])
    (1,  [1])
    ...
    (90, [90+])
) AS ca(Age, Value)
```

That view will normalize present your data in somewhat normalized form. You will not be able to edit the data in the view but you should be able to perform basic math and aggregation on the data. The 90+ value will still cause headache as it encapsulates more than one value.

Comment: Thanks @salman - agree a view for a presentational layer is a good idea.
Have marked up but won't record as answer as was hoping for a more succinct/ less hard coded option (eg less burden if groupings are to change later).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer by suggesting an alternative table design which will make life easier:

```
Area | Age | Count
A    | 0   | 123
A    | 1   | 65
...
B    | 0   | 442
```

Here we are storing each area's age in a separate *record*, rather than column.  With this design in place, your ask is easy to come by using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    Area,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 0 AND 19  THEN Count ELSE 0 END) AS [0-19],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 20 AND 39 THEN Count ELSE 0 END) AS [20-39],
    ...
FROM yourNewTable
GROUP BY Area;
```

Comment: I agree, that would be a better table design. Unfortunately I don't own this data and it has been supplied in the format above, so I need to manipulate it first. 
Separately that calculation will count how many times there is an age in the defined grouping, rather than summing the values within.

Comment: @JoeShark Then unfortunately your current query is probably as good as you can get.